# Cannot validate serde : org.openx.data.jsonserde.jsonserde

Tags: java, json, hadoop, hive

I have written this query to create a table on hive. My data is initially in json format, so i have downloaded and build serde and added all jar required for it to run. But i am getting the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
```

QUERY:

```
create table tip(type string,
  text string,
  business_id string,
  user_id string,
  date date,
  likes int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("date.mapping"="date")
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: could you find any solution for this error. I have the same problem and I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

I too encountered this problem. In my case, I managed to fix this issue by adding **`json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`** at **`hive`** command prompt as shown below:

```
hive> ADD JAR /usr/local/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

**Below are the steps I have followed on Ubuntu 14.04:**

```
1. Fire up Linux terminal and cd /usr/local

2. sudo git clone https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde.git

3. sudo mvn -Pcdh5 clean package

4. The serde file will be in 
   /usr/local/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

5. Go to hive prompt and ADD JAR file as shown in Step 6.

6. hive> ADD JAR /usr/local/Hive-JSON-Serde/json-serde/target/json-serde-1.3.7- SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;

7. Now create hive table from hive> prompt. At this stage, Hive table should be created successfully without any error.
```

`Hive` Version: 1.2.1

`Hadoop` Version: 2.7.1

Reference: [Hive-JSON-Serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

Comment: Every time I open the Hive prompt to query this table, I must run step 6 again (ADD JAR /usr/local/Hive-JSON-Serde/....).  Is there a config I can change to automatically load it every time?

Comment: To load it automatically, use the ~/.hiverc file.

Comment: Seems the structure has changes, I am getting this error javac: directory not found: /home/hadoop/JsonSerDe/Hive-JSON-Serde/json/target/classes

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the project cloned using the maven !

> mvn install
>   in the directory /path/directory/Hive-JSON-Serd
>   here we are in /usr/local