# Building GITHUB project using Maven

Tags: java, json, maven, hive, bigdata

I'm actually from BIG Data background want some help in maven. I'm trying to get a JSON jar from here for using it in my json tables.I have some serilisation/deserilisation code present on Github  at this location https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde .
I can see a POM file present in the main page of the above link ,May be it is  the Parent POM and there are other POM files present in the other folders present there as well.

> i want the built jar file out of json-serde folder presen there .
>   I'm following the steps from here [Cannot validate serde : org.openx.data.jsonserde.jsonserde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644351/cannot-validate-serde-org-openx-data-jsonserde-jsonserde)

So first of all i'm confused about the dependencies which pom file do i need to place inside /etc/maven.I actually tried running it and ended up with below observation

```
<i>`vaibhav@vaibhav-Lenovo-G570:/etc/maven$ sudo mvn -Pcdh5 clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.openx.data:json-serde:1.3.8-SNAPSHOT (/etc/maven/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.openx.data:json-serde-parent:pom:1.3.8-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException`</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch a snapshot which dependencies are not present on the maven central repository.

If you just need the latest released jar file then just fetch it from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keedio/openx/data/json-serde/1.3.7.3/json-serde-1.3.7.3.jar

If you are yourself using maven to build your software, then you need to add the following dependency to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keedio.openx.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-serde</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```